# Is there a Python function called "theory" like in Java JUnit for testing software?

Tags: python, testing

I have a question about the theory test in Python.
In the JUnit library, which is used in Java to test software. There is a class called Theory that can be used to create hypotheses on input with the help of @datapoints, @theory, assumption, and @runWith. Previously, I found a similar article at ([Unit test Theories in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30494423/unit-test-theories-in-python)). Parameterization is the technique I'm familiar with. In Java, parameterization is an independent concept.

Comment: If you already found that other question, how is yours different?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.